# Misplaced indent

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Looking at my [public CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/jasonpunyon), my name and other identifying info is indented oddly. It's the same way on my cv edit page. The line breaks in my current position are also weird.

[image: odd indent yo]

Comment: It even stole the space from "Stack Overflow"!

Comment: @TimStone: Nah that was my screwup.

Comment: You bought the company?! Congratulations!

Comment: @JasonPunyon I know, I'm just a smartass, sorry :P

Comment: I don't get it - No red free-hand circles...

Comment: Nice catch, styling conflict between Core and Careers; fix coming. CSS, you betrayed us.

Comment: @G-Wiz: What about the line breaks?

Comment: @JasonPunyon ah, that. Yeah, it looks OK when there's only a single title, but with multiple it doesn't. Fix going out soon!

Answer (score 1):

Styling conflict has been fixed.